# Modify OneNote page template when sending from Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-onenote-2016

When using the send to OneNote Feature from Outlook calendar a specific template is used by default. It adds the same information you can input by using the meeting details by hand.

Is there a way to modify the template that is used when sending from Outlook and add some more custom things?

Answer (score 0):

See the article
[Default template for Outlook items sent to OneNote](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/send-to-onenote-default-template-outlook) for details.

In OneNote, templates are assigned to a page when the page is being
created and cannot be changed afterwards. Therefore, you must change
the default template for the section that it will be sent to.

To change default template for a section:

- Select the Insert tab
- Click on the Page Templates button:
  [image]
- Select "Page Templates..."
- You may then select from a large number of templates.

To create a new template, create that page first in OneNote,
and go to the Page Templates pane as above. At the bottom, under
"Create new template", you will find the option to
"Save current page as a template".

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following steps to configure it.

1. In OneNote Select "File" from the Ribbon
2. Select "Options" from the bottom of the list (below Account and Feedback)
3. In the "OneNote Options" dialog, the fifth item down in the left column is "Send to OneNote"
4. There are 3 sections in "Send to OneNote" in the Outlook Items section
5. Here's where you set (or, in my case, reset) the email default for Outlook.  I don't think this can be found within Outlook - you have to be in OneNote to fix this.